# Vuejs typescript class based components cannot update data from external api

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I'm using VueJS with Typescript and class based components. I have the following code which gives me

`[Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "upcomingexams"`

UpcomingExams.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="card">
        <ul class="examlist">
            <li v-for="exam in upcomingexams" :key="exam.examId">
                {{ exam.examId }} on {{ exam.start }}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Prop, Vue } from "vue-property-decorator";

export interface Exam {
  examId: string;
  questions: string[];
  correctAnswers: string[];
  start: Date;
  end: Date;
  course: string;
  schools: string[];
}

@Component
export default class UpcomingExams extends Vue {
@Prop() upcomingexams!: Exam[];

mounted() {
    console.log("UpcomingExams component mounted");
    this.getExamsAfterToday();
}

getExamsAfterToday() {
    var date = new Date();
    fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/queries/Q1?todayDatetime=" + date.toJSON())
    .then(response => response.json() as Promise<Exam[]>)
    .then(data => (this.upcomingexams = data));
}
}
</script>
```

I have tried to switch the `Prop` to `data` by removing the `@Prop()` decorator. That results in the following error:

`Property or method "upcomingExams" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.`

Clearly, I am initializing it with the bang. i'm not sure what's going wrong.

Comment: You are trying to mutate a `prop`. You should only ever mutate `data`

Comment: Otherwise, you violate the concept of one-way data flow, which vue decidedly won't allow you to do anyway, as shown by the error

Comment: If I remove the `@Prop()` decorator I get a vue warn that `upcomingexams` is undefined on instance but referenced during render

Comment: well you are passing a prop to the component, you want to save the prop in a data attribute

Comment: you cannot modify data in a component that isn't solely controlled by that component. Unless, of course, you use a concept like vuex or flux

Comment: Which is the more advanced way of handling 1 way data flow

Comment: see https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow

Comment: I switched the prop to a data type. My fetch call isn't working anymore it seems, since it's not being set.

Comment: I'm relatively new to Vuejs, i feel like i'm missing something obvious here.

Comment: Use the vue dev tools to check the data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179128/discussion-between-haardik-and-derek).

Answer (score 0):

After about an hour of scratching my head, turns out bang initialization doesn't play nicely with Vue for some reason. Switching the declaration of `upcomingexams` to be

`upcomingexams: Exam[] = [];` got it to work.

Comment: To give a bit more context, when initializing an attribute in a vue component, vue adds getters and setters to the attribute so it can track and handle changes. When an attribute is set to null, like yours originally was, it cannot add those setters/getters, thus making the attribute useless for dynamic data